# Firebase: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to allow all my users read the data in `users/{$uid}/books/owned_books/` without defaulting to `".read" === true` in my `users` directory. Is there a wildcard I can use instead of `{$uid}` that will grant permission for a users to read other user's data?

I have already tried allowing the user to read `users` but I get the following error:
`permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

```
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "user_data": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "books": {
          "owned_books": {
            ".read": "auth !== null &&  auth.uid ===$uid ",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `".read": "auth !== null"` in `users` like below:

```
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid": {
        "user_data": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        },
        "books": {
          "owned_books": {
            ".read": "auth !== null &&  auth.uid ===$uid ",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```